# Android how to create Hidden file?

Tags: android

I am creating application which contains `database` that needs to be hidden in the SD Card. Can any one help to make a hidden file  in sd card?

Comment: Android does not have a concept of a "hidden file". The suggestion to put the file in a directory that is prefixed with a `.` is a convention that not all file managers, etc. will honor.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder which starts name with dot.

```
sdcard/.database/filename.db
```